# Django administration custom form display

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I'm trying to extend models.TextField for the case of Markdown:

```
class MarkdownField(TextField):
    description = "Text that uses Markdown for processing."

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MarkdownField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And I want to make it so that in any forms that have the markdown field (including administration), the [markdown cheatsheet](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux) `{% markdown_cheatsheet %}` is displayed near the textarea (perhaps on the right-hand side).

There is no documentation (that I've been able to find) that helps me figure this out on my own. I considered widgets but I think that's not what I want because I don't want to change the actual textarea.

I just want to specifically add the cheatsheet beside the textarea for any MarkdownField inputs.

Comment: why do not use [django-markupfield](https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield)

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't work well with 1.7 dev and Python 3.4.